# Carousel - add different pages to Carousel

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am receiving an error - "Carousel has no children".

I utilized the carousel sample from Xamarin.  Carousel works if the pages are the same.  My requirement is that my pages are different but I want it to work in a carousel.

1. Page 1 - Image
2. Page 2 - Buttons
3. Page 3 - Check Boxes

**MainPage.xaml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <CarouselPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  x:Class="CarouselApp.MainPage">
        <CarouselPage.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentPage>
                    <ContentPage.Padding>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0,40,0,0" Android="0,40,0,0"> 
                    </ContentPage.Padding>
                    <StackLayout>
                            <ContentView BindingContext="PageName"></ContentView>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ContentPage>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselPage.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselPage>
```

**MainPage.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CarouselApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : CarouselPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ItemsSource = CarouselAppDataModel.All;
        }
    }
}
```

**DataModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CarouselApp
{
    public class CarouselDataModel : ContentView
    {
        public ContentView PageName { get; set; }
        public static IList<CarouselDatModel> All { get; set; }

        private Carousel03 fl3 as new Carousel03;
        private Carousel04 fl4 as new Carousel04;

        public CarouselDataDataModel()
        {
            All = new ObservableCollection<CarouselDataModel>
            {
                new CarouselDataModel
                {
                    PageName = fl3
                },
                new CarouselDataModel
                {
                    PageName = fl4
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: XAML Page<br/>
<CarouselPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     x:Class="CarouselApp.MainPage">
  <CarouselPage.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ContentPage >
        <ContentPage.Padding>
          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0,40,0,0" Android="0,40,0,0" />
        </ContentPage.Padding>
        <StackLayout>
          <ContentView BindingContext="PageName"  ></ContentView>
        </StackLayout>
      </ContentPage>
    </DataTemplate>
  </CarouselPage.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselPage>

Comment: it's really unclear what problem you're trying to solve.  CarouselPage can contain ContentPage instances.  They do not have to be identical - they can contain any kid of content you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since your pages are all different, and you are using XAML... rather than use a data template just create three consecutive content pages in your XAML as below

```
<CarouselPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              x:Class="CarouselPageNavigation.MainPage">
    <ContentPage>
        <ContentPage.Padding>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0,40,0,0" Android="0,40,0,0" />
        </ContentPage.Padding>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Red" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <BoxView Color="Red" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage>
        ...
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage>
        ...
    </ContentPage>
</CarouselPage>
```

Comment: For anyone finding this working with MAUI, MAUI does not have a CarouselPage analog.